# Powershell - Can I scrape SQL file and compare results?

Tags: sql, powershell, compare

I am fairly new to Powershell and have run into a bit of a pickle.
I am trying to scrape a SQL script in txt file format. My goal is to check if every created (volatile) table is also dropped in the same file. And if not, output the name of the table which is not dropped in the SQL script.
On top of that I would like check if the "drop" of the table is AFTER "create volatile table" and not BEFORE, because that would be wrong syntax. Do you think it's somehow possible?

I tried to do it by extracting lines of codes where is the create table string, then using regex to get name(string) of the table and saving it to variable. I did the same with the "drop table...". Now I am trying to compared those two (string) variables by converting them to list, object or whatever. I feel like I am in dead end.

```
$vtMatch = Get-ChildItem "$packagepath\Scripts\" -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "create multiset volatile table VT_","create multiset volatile table vt_"
$vtMatch = $vtMatch.line
$vt = $vtMatch | Select-String 'vt_(.*?)(?=,)' -AllMatches | Select-Object -Expand matches | ForEach-Object {$_.value} 


$dropMatch = Get-ChildItem "$packagepath\Scripts\" -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern "drop table VT_","drop table vt_"
$dropMatch = $dropMatch.line
$drop = $dropMatch | Select-String 'vt_(.*?)(?=;)' -AllMatches | Select-Object -Expand matches | ForEach-Object {$_.value}

$missing = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $vt -DifferenceObject $drop -Property item
$missing
```

The variable $vt contains these strings:

```
vt_R_transaction_Dm
```

vt_h_bank_account
vt_DD_Agreement_Detail_1
vt_DD_Agreement_Detail_2
vt_DM_Agreement_Detail_Prebase
vt_DM_Agreement_Detail_RWA
vt_DM_Agreement_Detail_1
vt_posted_transaction
vt_DM_Corp_Objective_Specific_MAT
vt_DM_Party_Detail

And variable $drop contains these strings:

```
vt_DD_Agreement_Detail_1
```

vt_DD_Agreement_Detail_2
vt_DM_Agreement_Detail_Prebase
vt_DM_Agreement_Detail_RWA
vt_DM_Agreement_Detail_1
vt_DM_Corp_Objective_Specific_MAT
vt_posted_transaction
vt_DM_Party_Detail

Comment: There is no way we'd have any idea what the inputs/outputs of what you are showing here are. Thus leaving us all to guess at what you are using/seeing. Converting strings to a list is a matter of using split on a delimiter and moving forward from there, but you are not showing anything to work with.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry. I have added the strings in the question.

Comment: Can you give us an example of TSQL code with the expected result?